# Can two pulsed electromagnets generate a local net force?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I'm an old RPG:er, and in one of my hard sci-fi campaigns I used reactionless EMP drives on the starships. I've described below how I imagined they would work in concept.

- Arrange two electromagnets A and B such that when both are switched on, they attract each other.
- Place a non conducting but incompressible material between them, or embed the magnets in the material completely.
- Both electromagnets are constructed such that when switched off, they do not interact with existing magnetic fields.
- Turn on A. As the current starts to flow through the conducting element(s), it’s magnetic field starts expanding.
- When the field from A reaches B, turn on B.
- Now the field from A interacts with the field from B, and a force is generated between them.
- But since the field from B has not yet reached A, the force is in one direction only.
- Once the field from B reaches A, switch off both electromagnets.
- Once the field from B has fully passed A, repeat the cycle.

Intuitively this should generate a net local force while emitting an EM field that is stronger in one direction than the other. Global net force should be zero, as the field would interact with other things outside the engine.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but my Google-fu has failed to bring me any sort of answer or discussion around this. Probably because I don't know the relevant keywords to search for.

Comment: This is an interesting question but may not generate the attention you wish because the attraction of two bar magnets (or two electromagnets or whatever else have you) is actually surprisingly complicated. The basic problem is that you can prove that the magnetic force does not do work, so the attraction comes from induced electrical forces. In any case, the device presumably does not succeed because the force-propagation delay nevertheless obeys conservation of momentum, which is a consequence of continuous space-translation symmetry via Noether's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

This is radio antenna with two coaxial coils driven out of phase. It is similar to a 
[Cubic Quad antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_antenna)

[image: Cubic Quad]

except that the latter has one loop powered and the other is a passive reflector. According to [NC4FB Figure-4](http://www.nc4fb.org/wordpress/low-profile-6-meter-cubical-quad/) this has a radiation pattern predominantly in one direction. I guess the system you describe, with suitable spacing and phase shift, would also.

Since EM radiation carries momentum it would produce thrust (although not much).